# How to use max_concurrency() in Discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this piece of code:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
@commands.max_concurrency(1,per=commands.BucketType.default,wait=False)
async def function(ctx,arg1,arg2,arg3):
```

the `max_concurrency()` works, but when the max concurrency is met, i want it to send a message to the author that says the bot is busy, I've tried the `MaxConcurrencyReached` exception handle but it simply doesn't work, anyone know how to work with this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

After defining the function I want to put the max concurrency limit:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
@commands.max_concurrency(1,per=commands.BucketType.default,wait=False)
async def function(ctx,arg1,arg2,arg3):
```

Then you have to handle it with `on_command_error()` and `isinstance()`. For example:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if isinstance(error, commands.MaxConcurrencyReached):
        await ctx.author.send('Bot is busy! Please retry in a minute')
        return
```